# Run a UNIX script to use different versions of python

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-2.7

I have a UNIX script which is used to initialize the environment and properties of the project. It uses python. I had to refer the path. This will be used as a common file and used across multiple developers. Few of the machines uses Python 1.x and 2.x. Few others uses only Python 3.x.

So `/usr/bin/python` works for the machines run Python 1.x but it fails in machines running python 3.x. I have to explicitly change it to `/usr/bin/python3` to make it work.

How can I handle the situation to make the script run independent of the python version installed.

Comment: Python *1.x*!? A 22+ year old version?!

Comment: Usually when Python 3 is installed, the command `python` should be available and be an alias for `python3`. If the script supports both Python 2 and 3, then it shouldn't matter whether `python` refers to Python 2 or 3. In other words, it should work simply with `/usr/bin/python` either way, no?

Comment: I started in this line of work in 2008, and i've never seen python 1.x in the wild.

Comment: Maybe helpful: https://askubuntu.com/a/321000/345778

Answer (score 1):

Python 1 or 2 are dead obviously, but I'll try to answer your question

In this this case you should have seprate binaries for each python version, similar to:

- /usr/bin/python1
- /usr/bin/python2
- /usr/bin/python3

In your script define the version you want to use using [shebang](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2429511/why-do-people-write-usr-bin-env-python-on-the-first-line-of-a-python-script)

For example make a file `my_old_script.py`:

```
#!/usr/bin/python2

import sys

print(sys.version)
```

Give the script execution permission:

```
chmod +x my_old_script.py
```

Then execute it without specifying an interpreter:

```
./my_old_script.py
```

output:

```
2.7.17 (default)
[GCC 7.5.0]
```

Comment: That makes the script entirely dependent on which python version is installed, the question is how to make it independent.

Comment: That's simply not possible without some weird hacking, this is one why to handle tasks with different scripts and python versions. This how current must distro handle python2 and 3 distribution, in Ubuntu you will find python3, python3.x and python2 each point to a different version of python

Answer (score 0):

Python2 is dead (less so that python1, but still dead), so it should be less and less of an issue. If you are worried about python2/3 compatibility, there is [six](https://pypi.org/project/six/) and most things have been backported through the `__future__` module, hopefully those two should be enough for your use cases.